# BargainFinderMax REST API does not return fare for child

Tags: sabre

I use BargainFinderMax REST API.
I cannot get fares for child, but instead i get message "CHD NOT APPLICABLE - ADT FARE USED - VERIFY RESTRICTIONS" with adult fare.

I tried to use TPA_Extensions": {"XOFares": {"Value": true} 
with no success. Maybe i am messing anything else. please advise. Here is my request:

```
{

 "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {

     "Target": "Production",

       "POS": {

            "Source": [{

                "PseudoCityCode":"F9CE",

                "RequestorID": {

                    "Type": "1",

                  "ID": "1",

                    "CompanyName": {



                  }

             }

         }]

        },

        "OriginDestinationInformation": [{

          "RPH": "1",

           "DepartureDateTime": "2017-07-28T11:00:00",

           "OriginLocation": {

             "LocationCode": "DFW"

         },

            "DestinationLocation": {

                "LocationCode": "CDG"

         },

            "TPA_Extensions": {

             "SegmentType": {

                    "Code": "O"

               }

         }

     },

        {

         "RPH": "2",

           "DepartureDateTime": "2017-08-08T11:00:00",

           "OriginLocation": {

             "LocationCode": "CDG"

         },

            "DestinationLocation": {

                "LocationCode": "DFW"

         },

            "TPA_Extensions": {

             "SegmentType": {

                    "Code": "O"

               }

         }

     }],

       "TravelPreferences": {

          "ValidInterlineTicket": true,

           "CabinPref": [{

             "Cabin": "Y",

             "PreferLevel": "Preferred"

            }],

           "TPA_Extensions": {

             "TripType": {

                   "Value": "Return"

             },

                "LongConnectTime": {

                    "Min": 780,

                 "Max": 1200,

                    "Enable": true

              },

                "ExcludeCallDirectCarriers": {

                  "Enabled": true

             },

                "XOFares": {
                  "Value": true
                }

         }

     },

        "TravelerInfoSummary": {

            "SeatsRequested": [2],

          "AirTravelerAvail": [{

              "PassengerTypeQuantity": [{

                 "Code": "ADT",

                    "Quantity": 1

               },
               {

                 "Code": "CHD",

                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Age":      6

               }]

            }]

        },

        "TPA_Extensions": {

         "IntelliSellTransaction": {

             "RequestType": {

                    "Name": "50ITINS"

             }

         }

     }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for Child is CNN

According to sample request at Bargain Finder Max API Information page

```
<AirTravelerAvail>
<PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
<PassengerTypeQuantity Code="CNN" Quantity="1" />
<PassengerTypeQuantity Code="INF" Quantity="1" />
</AirTravelerAvail>
```

Comment: Thank a lot, you are right. It works now. It looks like child code was changed from last year or so.

Answer (score 0):

Bargain fare rest api provide child and infant fare.

```
{
"OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
"Target": "Production",
"POS": {
  "Source": [{
    "PseudoCityCode": "F9CE",
    "RequestorID": {
      "Type": "1",
      "ID": "1",
      "CompanyName": {

      }
    }
  }]
},
"OriginDestinationInformation": [{
  "RPH": "1",
  "DepartureDateTime": "2017-10-10T11:00:00",
  "OriginLocation": {
    "LocationCode": "EWR"
  },
  "DestinationLocation": {
    "LocationCode": "DEL"
  },
  "TPA_Extensions": {
    "SegmentType": {
      "Code": "O"
    }
  }
}],
"TravelPreferences": {
  "ValidInterlineTicket": true,
  "CabinPref": [{
    "Cabin": "Y",
    "PreferLevel": "Preferred"
  }],
  "TPA_Extensions": {
    "TripType": {
      "Value": "OneWay"
    },
    "LongConnectTime": {
      "Min": 780,
      "Max": 1200,
      "Enable": true
    },
    "ExcludeCallDirectCarriers": {
      "Enabled": true
    }
  }
},
"TravelerInfoSummary": {
  "SeatsRequested": [3],
  "AirTravelerAvail": [{
    "PassengerTypeQuantity": [{
        "Code": "ADT",
        "Quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "Code": "CNN",
        "Quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "Code": "INF",
        "Quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }]
},
"TPA_Extensions": {
  "IntelliSellTransaction": {
    "RequestType": {
      "Name": "50ITINS"
        }
      }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, i fixed a problem based on first reply provided in XML format. I modified my json request.